# "Back at his house in..." vs "back in his house in..."

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

What's the correct form? Or at least the most commonly used?

I found both instances in Google Books:

> On the journey home and [back in his house](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=938&tbm=bks&q=%22%20back%20in%20his%20house%20in%22&oq=%22%20back%20in%20his%20house%20in%22&gs_l=serp.3...13213.13213.0.13298.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.0.0.KTMKDy_g_jU) in Scy Chazelles Schuman
>   gave the plan his undivided attention.
>
> [Back at his house](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=938&tbm=bks&q=%22%20back%20at%20his%20house%20in%22&oq=%22%20back%20at%20his%20house%20in%22&gs_l=serp.3...82483.82511.0.83159.2.2.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..2.0.0.7m5H_aN5ue0) in Littleton, he checked the photoelectric panels'
>   gauges inside the front door.

- Is there any difference in meaning?
- Are the prepositions *in* and *at* interchangeable?

Comment: Correct form of what?  These are both perfectly good sentences.

Comment: This is the kind of question you could easily answer yourself simply by Googling *"back in his house"* and *"back at his house"*, and comparing the usage contexts you encounter in the hits.

Comment: There is a nuance difference, though, to a native speaker. Not perhaps a very important one, but one would expect a skilled novelist to distinguish.

Comment: I've taken up David Pugh's suggestion that there could be a subtle difference.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Thanks for the addition. Is it still a bad question? Should I delete it?

Comment: Leave it, see if anyone answers. The difference in meaning is marginal, you should be able to work it out yourself. And the post might prove helpful for future visitors.

Comment: For a non-native speakers of English, working this out on their is not easy to do.  The distinction is very slight and nuanced.  Even if you compare the results of a google search, the nuanced difference is unlikely to come through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference isn't so much in meaning as in nuance and it is very slight.

In the first sentence there is a sense of time elapsing.  If it had been written as

> On the journey home and back at his house in Scy Chazelles Schuman gave the plan his undivided attention.

there is still the meaning that while on the journey Schuman was giving the plan undivided attention.  However,
there is a *very slight* sense that *maybe* only upon returning home did Schuman give the plan his undivided attention, but the next day or a day or two later stopped thinking about it.  Again, let me **stress** that this nuance is extremely slight and may have nothing to do with the author's intent.

In the second sentence, "at" gives the sense that upon arriving at home the panel was checked.  If it were written "in", the immediacy of the checking of the panels is a bit weaker.

In either case, the difference is wording is extremely slight and I wouldn't be surprised to have others come along and disagree with me.